# get best match for django query

Tags: python, django

I have one thing and need suggest. Please help me on this.

my scenario is:
i have one model like ordercode
in this table i have prefix like

```
1  | US
12 | Canada
13 | UK
134 | Australia
```

and more.
then, i have string like 12345678, and i need to get best match for this string .

if user enter 12345678 best match is 12|Canada , if user enter 135678975 best match is 13|Uk, and if user enter 1345676788 best match is 134.

How can i do it in django query?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will require multiple request to check every char in the given order code...

```
def get_matching_country(order_num):
    i = 1
    matching_req = Country.objects.none()
    while true:
        req = Country.objects.filter(country_code=order_num[:i])
        if res.exists():
            matching_req = req
            i += 1
        else:
            break

    return matching_req
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, in logical I think it will return correct best match row, and if we have 100000 row table for compare, is this the best solution ?

Comment: you will have as many request as there are char in your order_num. never more. so with 11 char string, you can have 1 request to 11.

Answer (score -1):

```
def match_country(request, string):
    qs = Country.objects.filter(country_code__startswith=string) #or int(string) but you might want to write an exception if person provides a letters in that numbers.

    return ...
```

Have you saved your country codes as strings or integers?

Comment: it can't run since if the user enter 1345676788, none sting in the listed start with 1345676788 but ther is some who start with 13...